# New iCloud terms keeps coming up on my screen

Tags: appletv

Since a couple of weeks back, when I start (and sometime during usage of) my Apple TV this screen comes up.

[image]

(In Swedish and it translates to...)

> New terms of service for iCloud
>   You must accept the new terms of service before using iCloud on this Apple TV.

If I select `Show terms` I just gets the Apple TV settings, but it doesn't stop the "new terms" screen from appearing again later.

[image]
The same goes for selecting `Not now`...

How can I stop the annoying "new terms" screen from showing up all the time?
Can it be done on the Apple TV or do I have to use my iPad or computer?

Comment: I haven't experienced this problem, but if I were you I'd try logging completely out of iCloud on that Apple TV, rebooting it, and then logging back into iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Spiff suggested logging out of iCloud and then logging back in again solved the problem. As I logged back in again, then new terms of service for iCloud was presented and I was able to accept them.
Problem solved.